# WebAPI parameter is null after http.post

Tags: http, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending a http request to my Web API using Angular 2, like so:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({Email: email, Password: password});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ 'headers': headers});

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:64792/api/authenticate', body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => { ... });
```

In my Web API, I have created the following class:

```
    public class Login
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this class as a parameter, like so:

```
 // POST: api/Authenticate
    [HttpPost]
    public int Post([FromBody] Login login)
    {
        return 0;
        //return userRepo.AuthenticateUser(login.Email, login.Password);
    }
```

When it receives the request, the login object is empty:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Actually hadn't checked. I checked the "Request Payload" - is that what I'm looking for? It seems to be empty and says "No properties"..

Comment: @SteveG. Turns out the body is actually empty. Any idea why ?

Comment: @SteveG. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I have now solved the problem :)

Comment: Fantastic! Glad that I could help!  I'm going to delete some of my comments here so it doesn't show that we were so 'chatty'.  The mods don't like that.

Comment: May you please share the solution?

Comment: @MatiasMasso Sorry, I don't remember what the the problem turned out to be or how I fixed it. It has been too long :(